# compile time validation error in template metaprogram

Tags: c++

Trying to write a simple validator at compile time to check it the number given falls in the defined range as below.

```
template<unsigned N> struct valid {static const unsigned value = 0; };
template<0U> struct valid {static const unsigned value = 1; };
template<99U> struct valid {static const unsigned value = 1; };

template<unsigned N> struct validate
{
  static const unsigned value = valid< std::min<0U,N> >::value * 
                                valid< std::max<N,99U> >::value;
}
```

However, the above fails - 
error: could not convert template argument 'min<0u, 1u>' to 'unsigned int'
error: could not convert template argument 'max<1u, 99u>' to 'unsigned int'

Any ideas?

Comment: `template<0U> struct valid` should likely be `template<> struct valid<0U>`. `std::min<0U,N>` shoud likely be `std::min(0U,N)`. Note that this is valid from C++14, where `std::min` was made `constexpr`.

Comment: `std::min(0U, N)` will always be `0` since `N` is unsigned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, above code is not valid C++ code. The syntax you're using for explicit template specialization is not correct (and you're missing a semicolon at the end). Apart from that: `std::min<0U,N>` and `std::max<N,99U>` are functions, not function calls. You probably meant to write:

```
template<unsigned N> struct valid {static const unsigned value = 0; };
template<> struct valid<0U> {static const unsigned value = 1; };
template<> struct valid<99U> {static const unsigned value = 1; };

template<unsigned N> struct validate
{
  static const unsigned value = valid< std::min(0U,N) >::value * 
                                valid< std::max(N,99U) >::value;
};
```

[try it out here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Atemplate%3Cunsigned+N%3E+struct+valid+%7Bstatic+const+unsigned+value+%3D+0%3B+%7D%3B%0D%0Atemplate%3C%3E+struct+valid%3C0U%3E+%7Bstatic+const+unsigned+value+%3D+1%3B+%7D%3B%0D%0Atemplate%3C%3E+struct+valid%3C99U%3E+%7Bstatic+const+unsigned+value+%3D+1%3B+%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atemplate%3Cunsigned+N%3E+struct+validate%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++static+const+unsigned+value+%3D+valid%3C+std::min(0U,N)+%3E::value+*+%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++valid%3C+std::max(N,99U)+%3E::value%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aunsigned+a+%3D+validate%3C1000000%3E::value%3B%0D%0Aunsigned+b+%3D+validate%3C400%3E::value%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:67.60404949381328,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:32.39595050618672,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:57.33681462140993,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:42.66318537859007,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: My mistake as I typed out instead of copy paste on the specialisation part. But was a mistake in the syntax of min/max. Thanks!

Comment: @Binu Also, note that `N` is unsigned, so it can never be smaller than 0. So the whole `std::min(0U,N)` thing would seem rather redundant as it will always lead to the same result. Effectively, what you're doing here looks to me to be just an extremely complicated way of writing `static const unsigned value = N < 100 ? 1 : 0;`!?

Comment: its a good point on the >=0, but unsigned was an example too. The reason I am doing this is to use the output of this to std::enable_if as an additional template param to another class which then wouldn't compile if trying to instantiate outside the range.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply write:

```
template <unsigned N, unsigned LO = 0U, unsigned HI = 99U>
struct validate : std::bool_constant< N>=LO && N<=HI >
{ /* static_assert(LO <= HI); */ };
```

Note that any value of `unsigned` type will be greater or equal to 0.

Comment: @Binu Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that the correct way to thank somebody here is to upvote his/her answer/comment. Comments are for useful and practical discussions relevant to the topic.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, just did that :)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to what others proposed, with C++11 you can use `constexpr` for that purpose:

```
constexpr bool is_in_range (unsigned n, unsigned low = 0u, unsigned high = 99u) {
    return low <= n && n <= high;
}
```

Which you can force to evaluate at compile time (if all arguments are known at compile time) by using it in a context which requires such evalutation, e.g.:

```
static_assert(is_in_range(5u), ""); // can skip the message with C++17
```